# How to prove that $A\,\land\,B\,\equiv\,A\,\equiv\,B\,\equiv\,B\,\lor\,A $ is a tautology?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

How would one prove that the golden rule is a tautology without a truth table?

> $A\,\land\,B\,\equiv\,A\,\equiv\,B\,\equiv\,B\,\lor\,A $

I've been searching a lot and cannot find a demonstration. I've tried to simplify the formula using another inference rules to reach a true value, without success.

Any help or at least a hint would be very appreciated.

Comment: parentheses, please

Comment: I can’t figure out what you’re talking about for sure. The only “golden rule” I know looks nothing like this. What does it even mean to write all these triple-equals in a row? Do you actually mean that $(A\wedge B\implies A)\iff (A\vee B \implies B$? Or something?

Comment: @rschwieb not sure it's OP's fault.... see pg 7 here: http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psarb2/G51MPC/slides/LogicalConnectives.pdf

Comment: In computer science books, this formula is called golden rule.
And it is found in books without parentheses. You can place parentheses according your needs.
Eg: $(A\,\land\,B)\,\equiv\,(A\,\equiv\,B\,\equiv\,B\,\lor\,A) $
or: $(A\,\land\,B\,\equiv\,A)\,\equiv\,(B\,\equiv\,B\,\lor\,A) $

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen yeah... what a ridiculous notation.

Comment: Just to help understand why people are clamoring for you to clarify your notation, normally, this form of "chaining" equivalences is meant to be read as shorthand for $$(A \wedge B \equiv A) \wedge (A \equiv B) \wedge (B \equiv B \vee A)$$ which, presumably, isn't anything like what you mean by the formula.

Comment: So I guess the real points that need clarification are 1) Which of the several versions do you wish to prove? 2) Which deductive system do you wish to use to prove it?

Comment: Maybe a better way to phrase the problem is as follows. From your comments, this appears to be a mnemonic. When you encountered it in your textbook, the book explained exactly what this mnemonic is meant to help you remember, and how to use the mnemonic to do so. And you have mistakenly assumed that its use is wide spread so that you can refer to it without comment. But that's not the case; your question needs to include that context: you need to elaborate on what *precisely* you are trying to say, so that you actually pose a well-defined question to people who have never seen it before.

Comment: @Hurkyl in the book im using right now, this formula is presented as a axiom, and it says that thanks to the associativity of equivalence, this formula can be interpreted in different ways according the needs. 
Maybe this rule is used only in computer science or so, and i'm asking in the wrong place...

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen: The $\leftrightarrow$ connective is actually associative and commutative in classical logic, so each of the bracketings should be equally provable,

Comment: @HenningMakholm good call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(A \land B) \equiv A \equiv B \equiv (B \lor A) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$((A \land B \land A) \lor (\neg (A \land B) \land \neg A)) \equiv (((B \land (B \lor A)) \lor (\neg B \land \neg (B \lor A))) \Leftrightarrow $$

$$((A \land B) \lor ((\neg A \lor \neg B) \land \neg A)) \equiv (B \lor (\neg B \land \neg B \land \neg A)) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$((A \land B) \lor \neg A) \equiv (B \lor (\neg B \land \neg A)) \Leftrightarrow $$

$$(B \lor \neg A) \equiv (B \lor \neg A) \Leftrightarrow$$

$$\top$$

I used the following equivalences:

**Equivalence**

$P \equiv Q \Leftrightarrow (P \land Q) \lor (\neg P \land \neg Q)$

**Absorption**

$P \land (P \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow P$

$P \lor (P \land Q) \Leftrightarrow P$

**Reduction**

$P \land (\neg P \lor Q) \Leftrightarrow P \land Q$

$P \lor (\neg P \land Q) \Leftrightarrow P \lor Q$

**Biconditional Tautology**

$P \equiv P \Leftrightarrow \top$

Comment: Thanks man, this is what i was looking for.